Django module not found
I am just getting started, trying to configure the URLs with an app. However, whenever I try to run the server, it tells me the urls module is not found, even when I use the absolute path. I've included some of my code below.
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('custom_regions/', include("some\\absolute\\path\\placeholder.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
]

Considering I've been following the tutorial to a T, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

For one thing, the include() function needs periods, not slashes, between folder names.

I don't think include() would even work with an absolute path.  Please show us the actual include statement.

Maybe you haven't created the urls.py for the placeholder app?

You cannot include "some absolute path".

Follow these steps.

Notice that include function argument must be: 'appname.urls'.
And your app package should have a urls.py in this format:
 app_name = 'app_name'
 urlpatterns = [
     path('api/', views.func, name='name'),
 ]


Check your settings.py and notice these two sections:



ROOT_URLCONF = 'projectName.urls'
Your installed apps must include all those you need.


Still, if you have any problems I recommend checking out a simple project in django. You can visit this repo of mine with a really basic and simple sample: Javad-Ak/Learning-Logs


use name on apps.py and use here .
for example,
apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AflPointsTrackerConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'afl_mlm.afl_points_tracker'

urls.py
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('afl_mlm.afl_points_tracker.urls')),
)


Make sure following things,


firstly make sure you have configured root url in your django application in
settings.py file ,like so ROOT_URLCONF = 'application_name.urls'.
Include statement do not take absolute path to the urls.py , it should be app_name.urls
make sure both your files are named urls.py


if still not found please share your filesystem and settings.py
